# not able to show a loading message in aggrid react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

Im using Ag grid table to populate data based on an API call so far i was able to reload the table and show the data on changing the select input.My goal is to show a loader message say for 4 sec irrespective of the api response.But i was not able to get the desired UI for it.My page is as follows

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '../../assets/styles/inner/table.scss';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine-dark.css'
import VerticalDivider from '../../assets/icons/svg/vertical-divider.svg';
import SearchVector from '../../assets/icons/svg/search-vector.svg';
import CloseSearch from '../../assets/icons/svg/close.svg';
import { APIEndpoint } from "../../utils/axios";

import zoom from '../../assets/icons/zoom.svg';
import SliderCTA from '../../assets/icons/svg/slider-cta.svg';
import DownloadVector from '../../assets/icons/svg/download-vector.svg';
import ReloadVector from '../../assets/icons/svg/reload-vector.svg';
import ChartViewVector from '../../assets/icons/svg/chart-view-vector.svg';
import DownArrowVector from '../../assets/icons/svg/down-arrow-vector.svg';
import UpArrowVector from '../../assets/icons/svg/up-arrow-vector.svg';



export const ListViewGridComponent = (props) => {
    const{title,filtersList,setFilteredWidgetData,id}=props;
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    let inputRef = useRef();
    const gridApi = useRef(null);
    const [ rowsData, setRowData ] = useState(props.rowsData || []);
    const [searchSlidebar, setSearchSlidebar] = useState(false);
    const [gridAPI, setGridAPI] = useState(null);
    const [gridColumnAPI, setGridColumnAPI] = useState(null);
    const [warehouseArr,setWareHouseArr]=useState([]);
    const [warehouses,setWarehouses]=useState([]);
    const [selWarehouse,setSelWarehouse]=useState(filtersList[0]);
    const [filters,setFilters]=useState(filtersList[1]);
    const [message,setMessage]=useState("");

    const DataLoading = () => {
        return (
          <div>
            <span>{message}</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        setRowData(props.rowsData)
      }, [props.rowsData])

    const changeFilter=(e)=>{
      setFilters(e.target.value)
    }

      React.useEffect(() => {
        getWarehouses();
    }, [t]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (searchSlidebar) {
          inputRef.current?.focus();
        }
      }, [searchSlidebar]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setSelWarehouse(filtersList[0])
        setFilters(filtersList[1])
    }, [filtersList]);

    const preCompile = {
        warehouse: t('selectButtons.selWarehouse')
      }


      const getWarehouses = async () => {
        const resp = await APIEndpoint.get('warehouses');
        if (resp.result.length > 0) {
            setWareHouseArr(resp.result);
            const options = [{key: 0, label: preCompile.warehouse, value: ''}];
            resp.result.filter( (fieldValue, index) => {
              options.push({key: index+1, label: `${fieldValue.value}`, value: `${fieldValue.value}`});
              return fieldValue;
            });
            setWarehouses(options);
        }
}

  


    const onReadyHandler = (params) => {
        setGridAPI(params.api);
        setGridColumnAPI(params.column)
    }

    const onColumnResizedHandler = (e) => {
        console.log('onColumnResizedHandler:', e);
    }


      const rowClass = "tableRowClass";
      const getRowClass = (params) => {
        if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
          return 'tableRowClass';
        }
      };

    const reloadGridData = (e) => {
        if (gridApi) {
            console.log('Reloading data grid...');
            gridAPI.refreshView();
            gridColumnAPI.sizeColumnsToFit();
            gridApi.current.setDatasource(rowsData);
            console.log('Reloaded data grid.');
        }
        return true;
    };

    const onBtExport = () => {
        gridAPI.exportDataAsCsv();
    };

    const onSearchClick = () => {
        setSearchSlidebar(!searchSlidebar);
    }

    const onFilterTextBoxChanged = (id) => {
        gridAPI.setQuickFilter(
          document.getElementById('filter-text-box-'+id).value
        );
     };


    const onItemTypeChange = async(e) => {
      setMessage("please wait,Loading ...");
      gridAPI.showLoadingOverlay();
      const myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        setMessage('');
        gridAPI.showNoRowsOverlay();
      }, 5000);

    setSelWarehouse(e.target.value);
    let  wName=warehouseArr.find(w=>w.value===e.target.value)
    if(wName){
    try {
    const resp = await APIEndpoint.get(`portal/v1/widget/${id}?warehouseId=${wName.id}`);
    if(resp.success){
      setFilteredWidgetData(resp.data)
      if(props.rowsData.length){
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
      }
  }
    }
     catch (error) {
      setMessage('No Result found');
      gridAPI.showLoadingOverlay();
       console.log(error)
     }
       }
    }
    return (
    <>
        <div className="cmpHeadingBlock flexRow alignItemsCenter justifyContentSpaceBetween">
         <div className='mb-3 component-header-space-list cmpHeading'>{props.title || ''}</div>
            <div className="cmpHeadingRight flexRow alignItemsCenter justifyContentFlexEnd">
                <>
                {!searchSlidebar?<img className="icon-size" src={SearchVector} alt="Search icon"  onClick={onSearchClick}/>:<img className="icon-size" src={CloseSearch} alt="Search icon"  onClick={onSearchClick}/>}
                {searchSlidebar ? <input className='filter-text-box' ref={inputRef} id={`filter-text-box-`+props.id} type="search" placeholder={t('filters.searchText')} onInput={() => onFilterTextBoxChanged(props.id)}/> : null}
                <img className="icon-divider" src={VerticalDivider} alt="|" />
                <img className="icon-size" src={DownloadVector} alt="Download icon" onClick={onBtExport}/>
                <img className="icon-size" src={ReloadVector} alt="Reload icon" onClick={reloadGridData} />
                </>
                {(title==='Most declined card sectors per month/week'||title==='Physical quantity of products sale warehouse wise')&&   <img className="icon-divider" src={VerticalDivider} alt="|" />}
                {title==='Physical quantity of products sale warehouse wise'&&<div className={`dialog__description`}>
                <select className='select-input-dashboard-list'  onChange={onItemTypeChange} value={selWarehouse}>
                {warehouses.map( (item, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>
                ))
                }
                </select>
                </div>}
                {title==='Most declined card sectors per month/week'&& <span>
                <button className='dashboard-border-listview'>
                    <select
                    className='dashboard-button-report'
                    id="page-size" onChange={changeFilter}  value={filters}>
                        <option key="week" value="thisWeek" selected={true} >This Week</option>
                        <option key="month" value="lastWeek">Last Week</option>
                        <option key="year" value="thisMonth" >This Month</option>
                        <option key="year" value="lastMonth" >Last Month</option>
                        <option key="year" value="thisYear" >This Year</option>
                        <option key="year" value="lastYear" >Last Year</option>
                        <option key="year" value="betweenDates" >Between Dates</option>
                    </select>
                </button>
                </span>}
            </div>
        </div>

          <div
            id="myGrid"
            className="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
            style={{ minWidth: "600px",maxWidth:'calc(100% - 3px )', height: "250px",marginBottom:'1rem'}}
          >
            <AgGridReact
            reactNext={true}
            headerHeight={36}
            columnDefs={ props.columnDefs }
            rowModelType="clientSide" // clientSide,infinite,viewport,serverSide
            rowData={rowsData}

            onGridReady={ onReadyHandler }
            onColumnResized= { onColumnResizedHandler }
            onRowClicked= { (event) => {
                    console.log('a row was clicked');
                }
            }

            rowClass={rowClass}
            getRowClass={getRowClass}
            rowSelection={ 'multiple' } // single|multiple
            rowMultiSelectWithClick={true} // True:multiple rows to be selected with single click
            suppressRowClickSelection={true}
            rowDragManaged={false} // true: Enable row dragging
            singleClickEdit={false} // true: Enable edit row
            editType={''} //'': Cell edit, 'fullRow': Edit full row
            animateRows
            componentWrappingElement={'span'}
            rowDataChangeDetectionStrategy="DeepValueCheck" // IdentityCheck|DeepValueCheck|NoCheck
            showToolPanel={true}
            loadingOverlayComponent={DataLoading}
            // loadingOverlayComponentParams={{ message: message }}
            overlayNoRowsTemplate={`<span>${message}</span>`}
            // components={{
            //     loadingRenderer: function (props) {
            //       if (props.rowsData) {
            //         return props.rowData;
            //       } else {
            //         return '<img src="../images/loading.gif">';
            //       }
            //     }
            //   }}
            // CALLBACKS
            isScrolling={ () => { console.log('scrolling...'); return false; } }
            cacheQuickFilter={false} // for a performance gain
            sortingOrder={'desc'} // 'asc'|'desc'|null
            accentedSort={false} // true: sort by ascented charecters(Slow performance)
            excludeChildrenWhenTreeDataFiltering={false} // exclude child nodes from filter results

            alwaysShowHorizontalScroll={false}
            suppressColumnVirtualisation={true}

        />
           <span className="icon-enlarge-list">
             <img alt='zoom' src={zoom} onClick={()=>props.handleZoom(props.chartLabel,props,props.options)} />
           </span>
          </div>
    </>);
}
```

he i am using griAPI  function of AGgrid react to show overlay messages based on a time out in onItemTypeChange function.how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue is that you expect to see your grid overlay for some time after you load data into the grid, based on a timer.

But, the grid will hide your overlay when the data is loaded, so the timer will not help you keep the overlay visible after the data is loaded.

I'm pretty sure that the only way to keep the overlay showing is to delay loading the data into the grid.